# How can I write a if statement with multiple conditions?

Tags: java, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I am trying to write a if statement where if a is true and if either (b or c) is true then do something.

I've written this but I am not sure if the logic of it is correct.

```
if (critStatus == false && badStatus == true || pmBadStatus == true) {
//do something
}
```

Basically if critStatus is false && if badstatus **or** pmbadstatus is true then it should do something.

Comment: Sounds like you mean `if (!critStatus && (badStatus || pmBadStatus))`.

Comment: I like how the OP literally typed out the answer to his own question while asking it. :P

Comment: Btw, `f==true` should just be written `f`, and `f==false` should just be written `!f` .

Comment: Thank you all, I was unsure and I knew something was missing. But this was not worth getting -3 for =/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(A&&B)||C** or **A&&(B||C)** are not the same evaluated, the order will be depending where are the parenthesis.

You mean

```
if (!critStatus && (badStatus || pmBadStatus)) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so you have to write your condition like this:

```
if (critStatus == false && (badStatus == true || pmBadStatus == true))
```

See the Java precedence rules [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Don't compare boolean variables to `true` or `false`. Use `if (!critStatus && (badStatus || pmBadStatus))`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (critStatus == false && (badStatus == true || pmBadStatus == true)) {
//do something
}
```

all you need is parenthesis. before the parenthesis the statement was:

```
if ((a = true and b = true) OR c = true){
```